# AWS Add Account Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, hal, spinnaker

First of all I am new to spinnaker so I am still learning the ropes.  Said that, I'm adding an account to the aws provider like this:

hal config provider aws account add ServiceAccountSpinnaker \
   --account-id XXXXXXXXXXX \
   --assume-role role/spinnakerManaged

where the XXXXXXXXXXX is my actual account ID, i've created a user account named 
ServiceAccountSpinnaker with a configured role of spinnakerManaged,

All as specified in Spinnaker Documentation:

https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/providers/aws/

After executing the Hal command here's what I am getting back:

> - Get current deployment   Success
> - Add the ServiceAccountSpinnaker account   Failure Problems in default.provider.aws.ServiceAccountSpinnaker: ! ERROR Account name
>     must match pattern   ^[a-z0-9]+([-a-z0-9_]*[a-z0-9])?$ ? It must start
>     and end with a lower-case character or number, and   only container
>     lower-case character, numbers, dashes, or underscores
> - WARNING No validation for the AWS provider has been   implemented.
> - Failed to add account ServiceAccountSpinnaker for provider   aws.

So basically I have a problem with the account name, some enlightening is actually needed, since I've spent as an idiot, 45 minutes trying so many combinations to a simple thing.

I appreciate the help.

EN

Answer (score 1):

Note the requirement "It must start and end with a lower-case character or number, and only container lower-case character, numbers, dashes, or underscores". Your account name "ServiceAccountSpinnaker" is capitalized.

Keep in mind that this account name is only relevant within Spinnaker, and does not need to match any naming within AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely right, so the answer is based on two facts, 
1. this account name is only relevant within Spinnaker.
2. Changed my Account name from ServiceAccountSpinnaker to serviceaccountspinnaker

then I succeeded on adding an account.